# CaraBohemian malt

Tags: ingredients, specialty-malt, flavor, malt

I just got back from a trip to the brew shop to get some stuff.

They had a couple new malts I haven't heard of before.  One was this CaraBohemia malt.  It had an SRM of around 70L and was described as being intensitly caramel in flavor and aroma.

I had that definate crystal malt aroma to it.  I tasted some and it was sort of somewhere bewteen brown malt and crystal 60 in its flavor profile.

Anyone ever used it before? Any other info to be shared about it?
I was thinking maybe incorporating it into something like a miabock or O'fest/marzen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CaraBohemian](http://www.weyermann.de/eng/produkte.asp?PN=2&idkat=18&umenue=yes&idmenue=37&sprache=2) is the commercial name for a [Wyermann](http://www.weyermann.de/eng/) malt.

Its listed uses are as followed, from the Wyermann site:

Bohemian Lagers
Bohemian Dark Lagers
Bohemian Bock Beers
Bohemian Specialty Beers
Porter
Stout
Ales
Bock Beers
October Beers

So your instincts are dead on for the uses for this malt.  It is designed to be up to 15 percent of your total grist.

Other manufacturers likely have malts with a similar profile.  [Briess's Caramel Malts](http://www.brewingwithbriess.com/Products/Caramel%5FMalts.htm) are probably a close equivalent.

I have not used CaraBohemian myself. Wish I could be more help. Let us know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

I found no differences between Carabohemian and Caramunich II in my beers, when it comes to aroma and flavors. I think the only difference it's the base malt (bohemian pilsner or munich).

To be fair, Weyermann's bohemian pilsner malt is made from German-bred variety which only happens to be grown in Czech Republic, then is malted in Bamberg. The only "true" bohemian malt in Weyermann offer is floor malt which is made by Litovel in Martin, CZ.

Comment: Caramel malts are made from green malt. Terms like "Carabohemian" and "Caramunich" as some maltsers use are simply brand names and do not indicate that the malt is made by "caramelizing" a base malt such as Munich malt or Bohemian Pilsner malt.